# Modeling 2 related services using SOA

Tags: web-services, soap, soa

I will use an example in order to express my question correctly:

I'm trying to model a Blog that have **posts**, and **comments**. A post can contain multiple comments, and a comment belongs to only one post.

In this problem, I have identified 2 main *Entity Layer Services*: **Post**, and **Comment**. Now, lets say service Comment offers the operation "read" that will give me a list of ALL comments.

If I want a new operation to list all the comments for a given post, where should this operation be exposed? On the Comment service? The Post service? Or should I have a new Service belonging to the *Task Layer* for this operation?

Answer (score 1):

all the comments for a given post is a filtered query of the comments service, therefore I would include it at the comments service. Anyway there is no single approach to solve this need and it often depends on the capabilities of the product you are using to implement the data services.